# Parental control on Windows 10 for restricting computer usage

Tags: windows, windows-10, parental-control

I'm looking for a software that will enable me to set restrictions on computer usage. Basically this: "Allow computer usage between 9-10am and 2-3pm. Restrict computer usage otherwise".

Using Windows 10's family safety feature is not feasible for this case. I'd prefer a software that can be set with a password. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to restrict just internet access, or all computer usage? Your router probably has built-in settings to turn off internet access at certain times.

Comment: A lot of times this capability is built into your routers back end software. Try browsing the routers settings from your web browser.

Comment: @browly That was my thought exactly (+1). Further, the router can database place timed restrictions on a single device, based on MAC address, so that others can continue to use the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Parental controls in Windows 10 are pretty solid, but to use them you have to set the whole family up with Microsoft accounts and you have to create specific child accounts for your kids. If you prefer to use regular local accounts, you can still set time limits for how long any non-administrative user can use a computer.

For more information how to setup please visit [How to setup account](http://www.howtogeek.com/225323/how-to-add-and-monitor-a-childs-account-in-windows-10/)

Comment: The OP explciitly states that "Using Windows 10's family safety feature is not feasible for this case"

Comment: @Mawg - true, but I didn't get a sense that OP stated *why* the included safety feature is unsuitable. So it's perfectly reasonable to present an answer of the form "maybe you should take another look at a solution you dismissed, because it may be more capable than you thought".

Comment: "I didn't get a sense that OP stated why the included safety feature is unsuitable" - he says "I'd prefer a software that can be set with a password

Comment: @Mawg - That's still ill-specified. I am not familiar with the Windows 10 family safety features, but I am sure you can protect the administrator account with a password, and presumably it's the administrator which is configuring these features. Thus it will be exceptionally difficult for OP's family members (assuming they do not have administrator accounts and are not skilled hackers) to defeat the safety features. This to me is "set with a password". If this isn't what OP wants, they have to be more specific.

Comment: That sounds good (+1). However, the answer above does say "Parental controls in Windows 10 are pretty solid, but to use them you have to set the whole family up with Microsoft accounts and you have to create specific child accounts for your kids", which sounds like a pain.  The OP joined up 15 months ago, posted this & hasn't been seen since the next day - I doubt that we're ever going to get an answer to this one :-/